# Flutter - How to hide or set tablerow visible?

Tags: flutter, tablerow

I am using Flutter Table widget. I wish to hide one of the table rows based on certain conditions.

I have tried Visibility widget over Tablerow but it does not allow. I also tried boolean condition eg. bool ? Tablerow(...) : Tablerow(), it doesn't seems to work well as it gave null exception - likely Tablerow is empty.

```
child: Table(
          border: TableBorder.all(width: 1.0, color: Colors.black),
          children: [

            TableRow(
              children: [
                TableCell(
                    child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                            child: new Text('ID1'),
                          ),
                        ]
                    )
                ),

                TableCell(
                    child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                            child: new Text('Name1'),
                          ),
                        ]
                    )
                )
              ]
            ),

            TableRow(
                children: [
                  TableCell(
                      child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                              child: new Text('ID2'),
                            ),
                          ]
                      )
                  ),

                  TableCell(
                      child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                              child: new Text('Name2'),
                            ),
                          ]
                      )
                  )
                ]
            ),


            TableRow(
                children: [
                  TableCell(
                      child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                              child: new Text('ID3'),
                            ),
                          ]
                      )
                  ),

                  TableCell(
                      child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                              child: new Text('Name3'),
                            ),
                          ]
                      )
                  )
                ]
            ),

          ],
        )
```

**UPDATE:**

```
bool_row ? TableRow(
                children: [
                  TableCell(
                      child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                              child: new Text('ID2'),
                            ),
                          ]
                      )
                  ),

                  TableCell(
                      child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                              child: new Text('Name2'),
                            ),
                          ]
                      )
                  )
                ]
            ) : TableRow(),
```

Using the boolean method, bool_row is false, the 2nd condition "TableRow()" throw an error:

: The method 'any' was called on null.

: Receiver: null

: Tried calling: any(Closure: (Widget) => bool)

I do not know how to produce an empty invisible TableRow.

Based on the code above, if I wish to hide or set 2nd row to invisible. How can I achieve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How you used boolean condition? Did you use with setState?

Comment: I have updated the code on how I used the boolean method. The 2nd condition, I do not know how to make TableRow invisible or empty. It throws back error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do as below to hide and show table row programmatically where we took "visibilityTableRow" boolean variable and based on that we decide to pass something in table cell or not:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyTable extends StatefulWidget {
  createState() {
    return StateKeeper();
  }
}

class StateKeeper extends State<MyTable> {

  bool visibilityTableRow = true;

  void _changed() {
    setState(() {
      if(visibilityTableRow){
        visibilityTableRow = false;
      }else{
        visibilityTableRow = true;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      primary: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Table View"),
      ),

      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[

          Table(
            border: TableBorder.all(width: 1.0, color: Colors.black),
            children: [

              TableRow(
                  children: [
                    TableCell(
                        child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                child: new Text('ID1'),
                              ),
                            ]
                        )
                    ),

                    TableCell(
                        child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                child: new Text('Name1'),
                              ),
                            ]
                        )
                    )
                  ]
              ),

              visibilityTableRow ? TableRow(
                  children: [
                    TableCell(
                        child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                child: new Text('ID2'),
                              ),
                            ]
                        )
                    ),

                    TableCell(
                        child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                child: new Text('Name2'),
                              ),
                            ]
                        )
                    )
                  ]
              ): new TableRow(
                  children: [
                    TableCell(
                        child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Container(),
                            ]
                        )
                    ),

                    TableCell(
                        child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Container(),
                            ]
                        )
                    )
                  ]
              ),


              TableRow(
                  children: [
                    TableCell(
                        child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                child: new Text('ID3'),
                              ),
                            ]
                        )
                    ),

                    TableCell(
                        child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                child: new Text('Name3'),
                              ),
                            ]
                        )
                    )
                  ]
              ),

            ],
          ),


          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Hide/Show Table Row"),
            onPressed: () => _changed(),
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. I know that I need to provide the 2nd condition TableCell something but just that I can't figure out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same problem and I solved with this:

```
List<TableRow> _myRows(){
  List<TableRow> rows = [];

  if(bool_row){ 
    rows.add(
      TableRow(
          children: [
            TableCell(
                child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                        child: new Text('ID2'),
                      ),
                    ]
                )
            ),
            TableCell(
                child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                        child: new Text('Name2'),
                      ),
                    ]
                )
            )
          ]
      )
    );
  }

  //here add others Rows with rows.add(TableRow(...)) ...

  return rows;
}

// In Table Widget
... 
Table(
  children: _myRows(),
),
...
```